# How to use external functions in php?

Tags: php

I'm making several webpage which uses a single function in php a lot. I'm wondering how I can put this function in an external file and use it (I tried include, but it seems like it doesn't work that way), like putting all javascript in one file and put it in the header. Thanks

Comment: If on the same server, you can of course include a file from different locations, if on different servers, I'd go for something like svn externals.

Comment: include does exactly what you want. I can't imagine what went wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you're attempting the correct solution. Could you post some code so we can help you fix?

Comment: I think key here is _'several wepage'_ (sic), which to me means he wants the file with functions in _different_ projects, but I'll leave it to @hyh to clarify this.

Comment: @yi_H: I tried to do "include 'file.php';", which just contain one function. But it turns out after doing that the whole definition of that function is printed on that page. When I remove the quotation marks I saw " Warning: include(filephp) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/sample/4.php on line 19" (I'm working on localhost at this moment) "

Comment: @Wrikken see above comment, only one "at" is allowed.

Comment: @hyh: your function file should _also_ start with `<?php`

Comment: I did, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Wrikken, here is the sample code I put there:     <?php include file.php;
/* <?php fucntion f() blablabla ?> (I put this in file.php)*/
echo f();?>

And I just see the error message above.

Comment: @hyh: do quote the filename, otherwise PHP makes `filephp` of it instead of `file.php`. So, `require_once 'file.php';`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP code:

```
//include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path/to/myfunction.inc.php"); preferably:
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path/to/myfunction.inc.php");
```

For JS code:

```
<head>
<script src="/path/to/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

These work if you have the paths set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using classes, here is a way to include these very easy:

```
$includePath = dirname(__FILE__);
set_include_path( get_include_path() . ';' . $includePath );
spl_autoload_extensions( '.cls.php' );
spl_autoload_register();
```

Answer (score 0):

So, to summarize comment-solving:

1. *every* php code should start with `<?php`, even if the files are included, because otherwise PHP assumes it's raw content (goes into HTML mode so to say).
2. Filenames must be given as quoted strings, not as literally in the code.